# Restrict people and friends of friends from adding me as their friend

Tags: facebook

How can I restrict people, even friends of friends from adding me as their friend on Facebook?

Answer (score 3):

That's not something Facebook offers. "Friends of friends" is the most restrictive setting for "[Who can send you friend requests?](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=privacy&section=canfriend&view)"

At best, you can make it harder to be found, using the same settings page.

If you really don't want a particular person to send you a Friend request, you can block them.